# How to rotate an array in degree of 20,40,60,...200 using Python?

Tags: python

In Python, how can I rotate an array with 20,40,60,..200 degree? Actually, this array contains fits image and I want to rotate this fits image. I know that I can rotate image, but this image is in form of array.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,

-Viral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this? 
 [`scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate.html)